# How to add all the records from a subset in a dataframe by column wise in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

```
  Participant   ID   Test1 Test2 Test3 Test4 Test5 Test6 Test7 ... Test57
  ParticipantA  asd    2      4    2     3      2      3   4           7  
  ParticipantB  sxa    1      3    2     2      3      3   3           8
  ParticipantC  agff   1      4    4     2      3      4   2           9
  ParticipantD  asx    2      4    2     3      2      4   4           4
  ParticipantE  axp    3      2    2     2      2      2   3          96
```

How to get the summation of values of all the columns from test1 to test57 rowise while retaining all the unused column in the dataframe

Comment: Use `rowSums` i.e. `df1$Sum <- rowSums(df1[paste0("Test", 1:57)])`

Comment: Thanks akrun, this code worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

It would sum all rows with numeric values only.

```
df$Sum <- rowSums(df[sapply(df, is.numeric)], na.rm = TRUE)
```